# AVPlayer stop playing hls stream immediately after one or two seconds in iOS 10

Tags: avplayer, ios10, http-live-streaming

I have a live HLS stream， and `AVPlayer` works fine before iOS 9. When I play in iOS 10, it will stop immediately after plays one or two seconds. I enter this HLS url to safari in macOS sierra get the same result. Does Apple change something in new os version?

I capture HTTP package using HttpScoop，two `m3u8` requests in the beginning return the same content， same `EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE`, same `EXTINF`, then no more request be send, `AVPlayer` stop the connection. 
I have no idea how to solve this problem. Can someone give advises to detect what's wrong with it?

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-ALLOW-CACHE:NO
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:1
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:23

#EXTINF:1,
3581652.ts?wsApp=HLS&wsMonitor=-1
#EXTINF:1,
3581655.ts?wsApp=HLS&wsMonitor=-1
#EXTINF:1,
3581658.ts?wsApp=HLS&wsMonitor=-1
```

I got responses like above several times

------------------update----------------------

[Media Stream Validator Tool](https://developer.apple.com/download/more/?=http%20live%20streaming%20tools) is a tool Apple supplied to validate hls stream.

With this command line tool: `:> mediastreamvalidator m3u8_url`, I got following error

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
MUST fix issues
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Error: Playlist vs segment duration mismatch
--> Detail:  Segment duration 3.1600, Playlist duration: 1.0000
```

So, I modified the `EXT-X-TARGETDURATION` and `EXTINF` to match real duration. `AVPlayer` will send request in `EXT-X-TARGETDURATION` time, it will close the connection when same result back several times.

If `EXT-X-TARGETDURATION` too short, our hls stream server does not update m3u8 index, then same m3u8 file returned.

Comment: can you share the url?

Comment: sorry @RhythmicFistman live stream is private， I can't share it in public。 But I can share response from this url

Comment: same problem on iOS 10, how to resolve?

Comment: @crossle I solved this problem, check your `EXT-X-TARGETDURATION` and `EXTINF `,  see my update

Comment: @codiction thank you, i check now